# How to select two random id from the child table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using mysql. I have a parent table, a child table and a grandparent table :) Child table has a reference to parent using task_id. Parent references to grandparent using course_id.
I need to take two random rows from the child based on parent table. And I need to join data from the third table(grandparent). For example - child's table:

```
id     game_id      task_id              
1      52          5                                         
2      61          4                 
3      2           4              
4      63          5           
5      25          4               
6      70          5
```

Parent table:

```
id     course_id                   
4      1                                                
5      2
```

GrandParent table:

```
id     title                   
1      Course 1                                                
2      Course 2
```

the output

```
id     game_id   task_id  course_id     course_name
1      61          4          1          "Course 1"
2      2           4          1          "Course 1"
3      52          5          2          "Course 2"
4      63          5          2          "Course 2"
```

I have a query that does what I want

```
(select games.id, courses.id, courses.title from games
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON games.task_id = tasks.id
    LEFT JOIN courses ON tasks.course_id = courses.id
    where task_id ='172'
order by rand() limit 2)
UNION
(select games.id, courses.id, courses.title from games
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON games.task_id = tasks.id
    LEFT JOIN courses ON tasks.course_id = courses.id
 where task_id ='171'
 order by rand() limit 2);
```

but I have so many task_id's. Is it possible to make a loop to take all the games from task_id's array [171, 172, ...] ?
And second question - is it the fastest way to select two random rows from games table? Because I expect 10 queries per second in future. How to optimize it ? Move all the data to one table?

Comment: Your code is not consistent.  For instance, there is no `puzzles` table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, missed that, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions.  It is something like this:

```
select gc.*
from (select g.id, c.id, c.title,
            row_number() over (partition by task_id order by rand()) as seqnum
      from games g left join
           tasks 
           on g.task_id = t.id left join
           courses c
           on t.course_id = c.id
     ) gc
where seqnum <= 2;
```

I'm not sure why you are using `left join`s.  It seems like you do want matches.  Also, if you want to limit this to a subset of data (such as particular task ids), then you can include a `where` in the subquery.

Comment: thank you very much, it works, but where clause like  "task_id IN [171, 172]" is not working, but I can limit by where c.is_matching = '1'

Comment: I suspect `row_number()` is no faster than other techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with several 'fast' ways to pick random rows.  Each has some flaw, so you need to pick:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random